# how to resolve this error: (Warning: Illegal string offset) and (Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0)

Tags: php, mysql, web

Let's say I have search.php and edit.php. 
Inside the search.php they can remove and update some records. 
If the user clicks the "update" button, the system will redirect the user to another page called edit.php.
I successfully called the itemid.
but this happens..

```
<?php 
        $itemid = $_GET["itemid"];                                  
        $description = "";
        $classification = "";
        $unit = "";
        $quantity = "";
        $price = "";
        $reorder = "";
        $status ="";

        $record = MYDB::query(
                            "select
                                *
                             from   
                                item
                             where
                                itemid = ? ",
                             array($itemid),
                             "SELECT"
                        );  

        if(count($record) > 0)
        {
            $record = $record[0];
            $description = $description['description'];
            $classification = $classification['classification'];
            $unit = $unit['unit'];
            $quantity = $quantity['quantity'];
            $price = $price['price'];
            $reorder = $reorder['reorder'];
            $status = $status['status'];
        }
        else 
        {
            echo '<div class="fail">';
            echo  '<b>FAIL!</b> Item Not Found!</div>';
            die();
        }

        if(isset($_POST["btnsubmit"]))
        {
            if(isset($_POST["description"])){
                $description=ucwords(trim($_POST["description"]));
            }
            else{
                echo "Please Enter description";
            }
            if(isset($_POST["classification"])){
                $classification=ucwords(trim($_POST["classification"]));
            }
            else{
                echo "Please Enter classification";
            }
            if(isset($_POST["unit"])){
                $unit=ucwords(trim($_POST["unit"]));
            }
            else{
                echo "Please Enter unit";
            }
            if(isset($_POST["quantity"])){
                $quantity=ucwords(trim($_POST["quantity"]));
            }
            else{
                echo "Please Enter quantity";
            }
            if(isset($_POST["price"])){
                $price=ucwords(trim($_POST["price"]));
            }
            else{
                echo "Please Enter Price";
            }
            if(isset($_POST["reorder"])){
                $reorder=ucwords(trim($_POST["reorder"]));
            }
            else{
                echo "Please Enter reorder";
            }
            if(isset($_POST["status"])){
                $status=ucwords(trim($_POST["status"]));
            }
            else{
                echo "Please Enter status";
            }
        }

    ?>
```

This are the errors,

Warning: Illegal string offset

Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error basically means that you are calling an array by a key which does not exist. I would tell you which key that is but you have not provided the specific variable.

Say I have this array:

```
$array = ('some_real_key' => 'a very important value');
```

Now if I call this `$array['some_fake_key']`, given that our array does not have that `some_fake_key` then it will produce the error you are seeing. Same goes for your `0 offset`.

You are calling it in your code:

```
$record = $record[0];
```

That means that there's no `0` offset, which could mean a range of things... Again there's not enough data provided. But it would follow the same example as above.

To fix those issues you can use `array_key_exists()`:

```
if ( array_key_exists( 'some_real_key', $array )
{
    echo $array['some_real_key'];
}
else if ( array_key_exists( 'some_fake_key', $array )
{
    echo $array['some_fake_key'];
}
```

This will output only the first array key; and will output no errors.

### UPDATE

Thinking about it, I think your error may be produced from your variables as follows:

```
        $record = $record[0];
        $description = $description['description'];
        $classification = $classification['classification'];
        $unit = $unit['unit'];
        $quantity = $quantity['quantity'];
        $price = $price['price'];
        $reorder = $reorder['reorder'];
        $status = $status['status'];
```

You are not really `setting` them from an array; you may be wanting to call `$record['key']` instead of `$description = $description['description'];`

For instance this would look like:

```
$description = $record['description'];
// ... so on ...
```

Comment: @Samuel Whoops I missed all the $unit = $unit['unit'] and friends myself...

Comment: @RobertKevinSieras what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the culprit

```
$record = $record[0];
```

You cant be setting a variable as a none array with itself becoming an array with an uninitialized value. That's just crazy talk... :)

What do you think you are trying to do with that line?

Assuming $record[0] exists and its some kind of id, you could do...

```
$record_id = $record[0];
```

But you are using an associative array for all your other items, so where does the index of 0 come into the picture...

You'd need to perform a var_dump of $record to check you are getting what you expect.

Comment: I am using that line to capture an item id... and it can successfully get the id.

Comment: So why use 0 as an index when you could be calling it item_id or whatever its field name is like all the others you have used by their field names (associative) and not an index number?